# C# Working on WebBrowser from another class

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

How can I navigate `WebBrowser1` to a website, from another class file?

Bassically I have 2 classes, default one (`Form1`) and second (`MyClass`), in `MyClass` I have a method with is navigating `WebBrowser1`(from `Form1`) to some random site:

```
class MyClass : Form1
{
    public void navigate()
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.google.pl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8");
    }
}
```

Button

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)        
    {
        MyClass mc = new MyClass();
        mc.navigate();
    }
    }
```

Visual Studio is not showing any errors, and application is not crashing after I call this method(by button), but it still not working.

Im a Newb, soo please help me in easiest way.

Comment: you must show more codes, that code is not enough. how about showing, how do you create myclass and the connection to form1.

Comment: Post the code for the button click event handler and the code within MyClass where you are trying to navigate the WebBrowser control.

Comment: Where are you calling the `navigate` method from? Post that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MyClass:

```
public class MyClass
{
  public void Navigate(WebBrowser webBrowser)
  {
    webBrowser.Navigate(.....);  //you can navigate webBrowser in Form1 from here
  }
}
```

in Form1:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyClass mc = new MyClass();
    mc.Navigate(webBrowser1);   // send the reference of webBrowser1 to MyClass
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are inheriting `MyClass` from `Form1`, newing up an instance of `MyClass` in the button click handler will create a new instance of the form, which, I am assuming, is not what you want.

You have two options:

**First Option**

Remove `MyClass` altogether and just have the `Form1` class have this code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  public void Navigate(string url)
  {
    webBrowser1.Navigate(url);
  }

  private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    this.Navigate("https://www.google.com");
  }
}
```

**Second Option**

Or, if you are really sure that you want to subclass `Form1`, then keep `MyClass` but make two changes. Do not new up an instance of MyClass from within the button click handler. Instead, just write:

```
public class MyClass : Form1
{
  public void Navigate(string url)
  {
    webBrowser1.Navigate(url);
  }

  private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    this.Navigate("https://www.google.com");
  }
}
```

and, in the `Program.cs` file, change the line:

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

to:

```
Application.Run(new MyClass());
```

At any rate, even though either of the two options will work just fine, you need to ask yourself why you are creating `MyClass`.

Comment: Thanks soo much for helping me. This was just an simple example of my problem, I need to have both of those classes.
problem solved, Thanks one more time

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your code structure but I see that you want to control the navigation of WebBrowser control from a different class, is that right?

In your MyClass:

```
public class MyClass
{
    // Holds the instance of web browser control
    public WebBrowser webBrowser;

    //Inject the WebBrowser control
    public MyClass(WebBrowser webBrowser)
    {
        this.webBrowser = webBrowser;
    }

    public void navigate(string url)
    {
        this.webBrowser.Navigate(url);
    } 
}
```

And in your form class:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyClass mc = new MyClass(webBrowser1);
    mc.navigate("http://google.com/");
}
```

You can also store a single reference of MyClass in your Form class